# NSManagedObjectContext and performBlock, changes on iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have an old project (started on iOS 7) with this simple code:

in AppDelegate I create the managedObjectContext:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Then, I perform an update operation in a view controller:

```
    [context performBlock:^{
        [context deleteObject:anObject];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Error saving context");
        }
    }];
```

I'm sure that this code was working correctly on iOS 7.0, but crashes on the `performBlock:` call on iOS 8 with this error:

> Can only use -performBlockAndWait: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.

I can solve the error changing the init method of the NSManagedObjectContext instance like this:

```
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```

But I don't understand why this behavior changed. In the documentation of NSManagedObjectContext you can read:

> A consequence of this is that a context assumes the default owner is the thread or queue that allocated it—this is determined by the thread that calls its init method.

So, in my first example, using a simple `init` call, the queue owner of the context is the main thread.
The `performBlock:` call was made on the main thread too, so I don't understand why this error. Am I missing something or it's a bug in iOS 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `-[NSManagedObjectContext init]` is just a wrapper for `-[NSManagedObjectContext initWithConcurrencyType:]` with the argument `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`. This creates an instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` that uses the obsolete thread confinement model - which does *not* uses a queue. Contexts created using `init` or `initWithConcurrencyType:` with the value `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` passed are not compatible with the queue methods `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`.

Create your context using `-[NSManagedObjectContext initWithConcurrencyType:]` and pass either `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` as appropriate. The context that is created as a result *is* compatible with `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` and will uses the queue confinement model that was introduced in iOS 5.

Comment: Thanks. I think that the sentence I quoted from Apple Docs is misleading :-)